# creating Quick rate dynamically using radio buttons

Tags: android

I am creating an application which fetches a form for ratings, dynamically. But when I implement this code, the radio group selects 2 options (radio buttons). I want to take rating in the form of radio buttons and the user will be able to select only 1 radio button. Check my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {

        LinearLayout lay_hori=new LinearLayout(this);
        lay_hori.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        TextView optionText=new TextView(this);
        optionText.setText(current_ques.option_text[i]);
        optionText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        optionText.setWidth(110);
        rg_rating[i]=new RadioGroup(this); //radio group
        rg_rating[i].setMinimumHeight(30);
        rg_rating[i].setId(i);
        rg_rating[i].setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            rb_rating[j]=new RadioButton(this); //radio buttons
            rb_rating[j].setId(j);

            rg_rating[i].addView(rb_rating[j]);   
            Log.i("rg_rating[i]", ""+rg_rating[i]);
            Log.i("rb_rating[j]",""+ rb_rating[j]);

        }
        Log.i("rg_rating[i]Child", ""+rg_rating[i].getChildCount()); //it returns that each radio group has 4 child,correct

        rg_rating[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkRadioGroup);

        lay_hori.addView(optionText);
        lay_hori.addView(rg_rating[i]);
        layout_main.addView(lay_hori);

    }
```

but at run time in a radio group,radio buttons select 2 options rather than 1

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the XML for the layout?

Comment: My requirements are to make it in a dynamic way.

Comment: Edited your question to include the `i` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that adding an array of Radio Buttons in an array of Radio Groups is not a good idea.

I didn't get a chance to test your code, but can you try the following code?

I have just stopped using an array of Radio Buttons, because ultimately you're adding only one element to the radio group inside the `j` loop.
Please correct any errors that you might encounter.

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{

    LinearLayout lay_hori=new LinearLayout(this);
    lay_hori.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    TextView optionText=new TextView(this);
    optionText.setText(current_ques.option_text[i]);
    optionText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    optionText.setWidth(110);
    rg_rating[i]=new RadioGroup(this); //radio group
    rg_rating[i].setMinimumHeight(30);
    rg_rating[i].setId(i);
    rg_rating[i].setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        rb_rating=new RadioButton(this); //radio buttons
        rb_rating.setId(j);

        rg_rating[i].addView(rb_rating);   
        Log.i("rg_rating[i]", ""+rg_rating[i]);
        Log.i("rb_rating[j]",""+ rb_rating.getId());

    }
    Log.i("rg_rating[i]Child", ""+rg_rating[i].getChildCount()); //it returns that each radio group has 4 child,correct

    rg_rating[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkRadioGroup);

    lay_hori.addView(optionText);
    lay_hori.addView(rg_rating[i]);
    layout_main.addView(lay_hori);

}
```

Comment: applied ur code but,still it works the same..it select 2 radio buttons in a group

Comment: I perhaps don't get you. does it let you select more than one radio buttons in the radio group, or does it select two radio buttons at once when you click any one radio button ?

Comment: it selects more than one radio button in a radio group

Comment: Okay, that means it lets you select more than one radio buttons in a group, while ideally it should let you select only one. I'll see the code once again and get back to it.